# How to dynamically change DataPointStyle on wpf line chart from dataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged event

Tags: wpf, colors, line, charts

i'm using the WPFToolkit to create a line chart with multiple LineSeries(multiple colors). I have a DataGrid control where DataGrid.RowCount = LineSeriesCount. The datagrid displays relevant data for each line in the chart.

I need to highlight(change its color to Black) the line in the chart when i select the respective datagrid upon dataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged.

i tried the below link but it didn't help: [Change a style dynamically in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821573/change-a-style-dynamically-in-wpf)

So var dpStyle = new Style() { BasedOn = originalStyle }; is not working.

I'm using below code to create the necessary Style:

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        dataGrid1.Width = mcChart.Width;
        HighlightedBlackDataPointStyle = new Style(typeof(LineDataPoint));
        HighlightedBlackDataPointStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden));            HighlightedBlackDataPointStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.OpacityProperty, 0.01));            HighlightedBlackDataPointStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
        this.Resources.Add("HighlightedBlackDataPointStyle", HighlightedBlackDataPointStyle);


    }
```

This is how i'm trying to set the above Style:

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            mcChart.Series.OfType<LineSeries>().ElementAt(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex).DataPointStyle = HighlightedBlackDataPointStyle;
            mcChart.Series.OfType<LineSeries>().ElementAt(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex).Refresh();
            mcChart.Series.OfType<LineSeries>().ElementAt(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex).UpdateLayout();
            mcChart.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
```

This is changing the color of Legend to black but not the intended line.

I've added all the lineSeries in C# codebehind by setting the Sytle while creating it. I do not have any Style definition in XAML. So, not sure if i can use the DynamicResource Binding from XAML.

Please let me know how can i achieve this from C# code behind rather than XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is rather outdated, but I will answer because maybe someone has the same problem.

Actually it is not as difficult as it seems.
To change the color of line just use the `Background` property of `LineSeries`:

```
    private Brush previousColor;

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RemovedItems != null && e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var removedItem = (ItemViewModel)e.RemovedItems[0];
            var line = chart.Series.OfType<LineSeries>().FirstOrDefault(ls => (int)ls.Tag == removedItem.Id);

            line.Background = previousColor;
        }
        if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var selectedItem = (ItemViewModel)e.AddedItems[0];
            var line = chart.Series.OfType<LineSeries>().FirstOrDefault(ls => (int)ls.Tag == selectedItem.Id);

            previousColor = line.Background;
            line.Background = Brushes.Black;
        }
    }
```

I use the `Tag` property because the row index of item can be changed by sorting, whereas Id is always the same.

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="chart" DataContext="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <charting:Chart.Series>
            <charting:LineSeries DataContext="{Binding [0]}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartItems}" Title="{Binding Title}" Tag="{Binding Id}" 
                                 IndependentValuePath="XValue"  DependentValuePath="YValue" />
```

I haven't posted the code of the `ItemViewModel` and the xaml of the `DataGrid`, but I think that the main idea is clear.