# How can I set value of style with Configuration File?

Tags: wpf

I want set property for all the label of my solution .
so i write style in app.xaml but i want create the possibility for users
that they can change value of its style.
help me to set the value with configuration file 
value ← configurationmanager.appsetting.get(" ... ").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using ConfigurationManager you could bind property values in a style to [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx). Assume an application setting `ButtonBackground` of type `SolidColorBrush`, the app.config would contain this:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <TestApp.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="ButtonBackground" serializeAs="String">
            <value>#FF008000</value>
        </setting>
    </TestApp.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

In App.xaml you could bind a style property to an application setting like this:

```
<Application x:Class="TestApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:p="clr-namespace:TestApp.Properties"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=ButtonBackground}"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... is not possible to change an style once used. But you can take a simple workaround. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821573/change-a-style-dynamically-in-wpf).