# Dynamic value use as resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In App.xaml I have the code as following:

```
<Application x:Class="CCE_Reborn.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CCE_Reborn"
         StartupUri="AdminWindow.xaml"
         xmlns:Knight="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Application.Resources>
    <Knight:Double x:Key="ButtonFontSize">18</Knight:Double>
</Application.Resources>
```

How can I calculate the ButtonFontSize value dynamically for the user to custom? For example like: `<Knight:Double x:Key="ButtonFontSize">someMethod(parameters)</Knight:Double>`

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9262625/1136211 ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Btw, I haven't try that yet. But indeed, it is what I am looking for.