# Background change using LinearGradient

Tags: c#, wpf, background

I'm programming in WPF(C#). I'm trying to define some thing to change skin of program.

I use this code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="RFID.OperationWindow" Title="OperationWindow" Height="768" Width="1366" ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="AquaGradient" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF6F6F6" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEAE8E8" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCD9D9" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF46AFBF" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE0DDDD"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF4EDAF0" Offset="0.018"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF75C2BF" Offset="0.964"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GreenGradient" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.082"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.071"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0FFB2F" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Window.Resources>
```

how can I assign LinearGradientBrush to a control Background ?
some thing like this:

I use `AquaGradient` for each background of controls. How can I assign `GreenGradient` to all of background dynamically?

for example some thing like this:

```
AquaGradient = GreenGradient;
```

Comment: What is `imageInsertUser`'s type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change a style dynamically in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821573/change-a-style-dynamically-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like :

`imageInsertUser.Background = Application.Current.FindResource("GreenGradient");`

but usually you want to do it in xaml

```
<Control Background="{StaticResource GreenGradient}">
```

Comment: You should look for "Triggers"