# Access the Setter property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have next UserControl:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Test.Views.NavigationMenu"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:RTUforWindows8.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HomeAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="HomeAppBarButton"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="ewffgwefwfwefwefwe"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE10F;"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button
        Style="{StaticResource HomeAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <Button
        Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And in my code i want to change the:

```
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="ewffgwefwfwefwefwe"/>
```

Value to something, i do:

```
NavigationMenu NM = new NavigationMenu();
        var style = (NM.Resources["HomeAppBarButtonStyle"] as Style).Setters[1];
```

And cant figure out how to enter set this value?

How could this should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setters are sealed. Even if you cast them as Setter to have access to the property Value in place of SetterBase you will get a runtime exception when you will try to modify them.

I think you can find a solution to do what you want in this topic :
[Change a style dynamically in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821573/change-a-style-dynamically-in-wpf)