# How to change the font size in two different controls of WPF usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

I have Created and Implemented WPf UserContol like Window8 PasswordBox. When I Change the Font Both Textbox and Inner Button has Changed. Unfortunately Button Font size not suitable when textbox font size has perfect. (See the Image - Second Button has perfect button font size, but textbox has not. And third Button has not perfect, but textbox has perfect font size)

How Can I make to set two Controls font size while Implementation? Like the Property Button_fontSize and textbox_fontSize.

My Usercontol XAML Code:

```
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ButtonWithoutHover" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Name="border" 
                            BorderThickness="3"                                                        
                            BorderBrush="White"                            
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" >
                <DockPanel Canvas.Right="2" Canvas.Top="2">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithoutHover}" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="onButtonClick" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Label Content="->" Foreground="White" />
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Name="txtNumber" DockPanel.Dock="Left" >
                    </TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
```

Implementation XMAL Code:

```
 <NumText:UserControl1 Click="UserControl1_Click" FontSize="9" Background="Red" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="160,46,206,229" />
        <NumText:UserControl1 Click="UserControl1_Click" FontSize="20" Background="Red" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="121,104,173,145" />
        <NumText:UserControl1 Background="Red" FontSize="36" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="121,180,173,69" />
```

[image: e]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I've done in my work is create a `Double` resource to set the `FontSize` property. I believe it will solve your problem:

First, declare the namespace in your XAML file:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then create two distinct `Double` "variables" with `x:Key`:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="SmallFont">10</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="LargeFont">35</sys:Double>
```

At last set your Control's `FontSize` property:

```
FontSize="{DynamicResource SmallFont}"
```

or

```
FontSize="{DynamicResource LargeFont}"
```

If I understood you correctly, this is how I've done!
 Hope it Helps.

Comment: Dear Its help to set the fonts in User-control. But how can I Give the Value while implementing in application. Your Code is look like HOT CODE.

Comment: in code you'll need just set it like this: UserControlTable1.RecordListView.Resources["ListFontSize"] = 16; at leas here it is described very well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821573/change-a-style-dynamically-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

You have overcomplicated the situation unnecessarily... you don't need different sized fonts, or `DockPanel`s, or `Border`s. Instead of all this, just let the content size the `UserControl`, not the other way around. Try this simplified example (to use *in* the `Usercontrol`):

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="jagadees" BorderThickness="0" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithoutHover}" 
Background="Red" Foreground="White" Content="->" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

My whole point was that if you restructured your XAML then you would see that you didn't need to use different font sizes. However, if you are resolute that you do, then just implement a simple `Converter` class to change the size for one of the elements:

```
public class DoubleToLargerDoubleConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(double)) return false;
        double amountToEnlargeBy = 0;
        if (parameter == null || double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out amountToEnlargeBy)) return false;
        double doubleValue = (double)value;
        return doubleValue + amountToEnlargeBy;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

As you never actually said which text you wanted bigger, I'm just guessing that the `Button` text should be bigger. In this case, you'd use it like this:

```
<Label Content="->" Foreground="White" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Converter={StaticResource 
    DoubleToLargerDoubleConverter}, ConverterParameter=5.0}" />
```

I'm going to assume that you know how to use a `Converter`, so let me know if you don't. Just set the amount that you want the font size to be enlarged by in the 
`Binding.ConverterParameter` property.

Comment: Actuality you have not noticed my button content is a label. Button.Content>
                            <Label Content="->" Foreground="White" />
                        </Button.Content>

Comment: Yes I did... I just didn't need to use a `Label` to get the same output. Did you try this code?. What's so special about using a `Label` there?

Comment: ya I tried your code without label. but same problem is there. see my question when I set the font size in UserContol, Both Textbox and Button take that size. So some times texbox font i big or button font size is big. So I decide to set two type of fontsize in UserContol.