# WPF adding style triggers dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was trying to add some WPF events to my control dynamically. I also tried adding event outside the Loaded event, but the style is null at that time. I don't know what should I do.

Here is my code:

```
public tagged_button()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += delegate
    {

        Setter setter = new Setter();
        setter.Property = tagged_button.BackgroundProperty;
        setter.Value = Brushes.Red;

        Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
        trigger.Property = UIElement.IsMouseOverProperty;
        trigger.Value = true;
        trigger.Setters.Add(setter);

        Style style = this.Style;
        style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

        this.Style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    };

}
```

But I get this error. :

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509

  Translated to English: "After a 'TriggerCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified."

  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.TriggerCollection.CheckSealed()
   at System.Windows.TriggerCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, TriggerBase item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at UI_Deneme.user_controls.tagged_button.<.ctor>b__4_0(Object <p0>, RoutedEventArgs <p1>)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   ...
```

I think I should add that trigger not after "Loaded" event, but I don't know when to add it. When should I add my trigger?

Comment: I think Thomas Levesque's answer to this question might apply https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821757/5869304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[new Style(Type, Style)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Style__ctor_System_Type_System_Windows_Style_)

You need to make a copy of the style.
Modify this copy.
And write it down instead of the original.

```cs
    Style styleCopy = new Style(GetType(), Style);
    styleCopy.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    Style = styleCopy;
```

**P.S. I will clarify.**
This is not a copy of the style, but the creation of a new style for the type of the current Window and based on the current style used by this Window.